# numpy 3 dimension array middle indexing bug

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I seems found a bug when I'm using python 2.7 with numpy module:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(3*4*5).reshape(3,4,5)
x
```

Here I got the full 'x' array as follows:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]],

       [[40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
        [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
        [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]]])
```

Then I try to indexing single row values in sheet [1]:

```
x[1][0][:]
```

Result:

```
array([20, 21, 22, 23, 24])
```

But something wrong while I was try to indexing single column in sheet [1]:

```
x[1][:][0]
```

Result still be the same as previous:

```
array([20, 21, 22, 23, 24])
```

Should it be array([20, 25, 30, 35])??

It seems something wrong while indexing the middle index with range?

Comment: I think you want to use  `x[1, :, 0]` rather than `x[1][:][0]`. The second one takes the 1st element from the outermost axis and then from the returned array, it returns all, and from the returned array it takes the 0th element, again from the outermost axis.

Comment: Or alternately which shows the complete workings... a[1,:,:][:,0]
array([20, 25, 30, 35]) .... slice the middle, then the column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a bug.

When you use `[:]` you are using slicing notation and it takes all the list:

```
l = ["a", "b", "c"]
l[:]
#output:
["a", "b", "c"]
```

and in your case:

```
x[1][:]
#output:
array([[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]])
```

What you realy wish is using numpy `indexing` notation:

```
x[1, : ,0]
#output:
array([20, 25, 30, 35])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. `x[1][:][0]` is not a multiple index ("give me the elements where first dimension is 1, second is any, third is 0"). Instead, you are indexing three times, three objects.

```
x1 = x[1]     # x1 is the first 4x5 subarray
x2 = x1[:]    # x2 is same as x1
x3 = x2[0]    # x3 is the first row of x2
```

To use multiple index, you want to do it in a single slice:

```
x[1, :, 0]
```